# Why HTTP Rest has different methods like GET, PUT, POST instead of just one or no method at all?

Tags: rest, http

Why do we have different methods for HTTP request. GET can not send data(body) and can only request something only through URL params. Put is like changing a field value on the server and Post performs an operation everytime we execute it (concept of Idempotence).

Why can't there be one method or no method at all ?
Why can't there be just a simple HTTP request where we can send data if we want. Now it depends on server logic how it wants to process that request based on the request content (data / body). If the server wants to just execute it like a get request & return something or perform an operation like a POST request & return something. It would have been more simpler.

Comment: Ahhahha may I joke (partially). Because in AWS POST messages cost much more than GET messages. I dont joke.

Comment: The different methods serve different intentions expressed by the caller as well as they convey different promises in regards to the content. Read up on safe and idempotency as well as on the [semantics of each method](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3)

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't there be just a simple HTTP request where we can send data if we want

Because that's not how HTTP works. [Each HTTP request has a required request method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1).

REST leverages this by reusing the semantics of the methods.

Comment: ok but why HTTP is not made to work that way. Wouldn't it be more simple if it is just like a simple message with a body. No need to specify any request method. Once a client sends the message, the server logic would decide how to process it based on the message body(content).  I'm actually not getting the concept of putting the request methods in a Http request.

Comment: Because HTTP is resource-oriented. It was invented to share and modify documents. You GET a document to read it, POST it to create it and PUT it to update it. Why does SQL have SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE statements? To make your intentions clear.

Comment: In a database we actually tell the database what to do using statements like INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE. But here we are not telling the server what to do based on client http request method. It is actually our logic on the server side for the web services which decides what to do. So I can write a DELETE query in a GET Web service on the server side. In this case the intentions won't be clear. So we are just using the data which is coming from the Http Request not the Http request method. So that's why I'm wondering the use of specifying the HTTP method in a HTTP Request.

Comment: Just as with SQL, to state the intent of the caller. The bodies for a number of requests could be the same, the intent is differentiated by the method.

Comment: @TusharArora if you delete something based on a received GET request you violate the protocol and thus risk of being not compliant with other clients. Think of a crawler which assumes that invoking URIs via GET is safe when it is actually deleting data that way. You can't blame the crawler then but only the implementor of that service as he didn't follow the protocol

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't there be one method or no method at all ? Why can't there be just a simple HTTP request where we can send data if we want.

Because describing the semantics of the messages in a consistent way allows generic components to participate in a meaningful way.

For instance, the semantics of a given request are constrained by the [common method properties](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2); if the metadata of the message describes itself as [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2), then generic participants know that, in the event that a response is lost, they can simply repeat the message.

Likewise, if a message is known to be [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), then each of the components know that the message can be dispatched speculatively -- allowing caches to prefetch representations that you may need, communicating to spiders that the content is safe for retrieval and so on.

The HTTP methods support finer grains of distinction; GET vs HEAD, PUT vs DELETE, POST vs PATCH.  And of course there are [extensions](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) that support other semantics as well.

From the perspective of [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), it doesn't have to be a *method* per se, so long as the semantics are expressed in such a way that generic components can act on it.  HTTP happens to have used [methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4).

> The request method token is the primary source of request semantics; it indicates the purpose for which the client has made this request and what is expected by the client as a successful result.

You are absolutely right that no method at all would be much simpler.  But it would also be a lot less powerful: you lose the ability to leverage generic components (like web browsers, caching proxies).  The metadata constraints are what make the web possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the **semantics of the request**. From the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> The request method token is the primary source of request semantics;
> it indicates the purpose for which the client has made this request
> and what is expected by the client as a successful result.

Here's a brief description of some HTTP methods defined in the RFC 7231 (click the links to check the full method definition):

- [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1): Transfer a current representation of the target resource.
- [`HEAD`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2): Same as `GET`, but only transfer the status line and header section.
- [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3): Perform resource-specific processing on the request payload.
- [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4): Replace all current representations of the target resource with the request payload.
- [`DELETE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5): Remove all current representations of the target resource